# ¿Existe la manera de agregar datos de sql dependiendo de la fila del GridView? ASPX y C# con Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Mi idea es mostrar en un GridView información que tengo de tablas en mi base de datos, como necesito mostrar dos Códigos de un producto, tengo que llamar a dos SELECT, uno para cada código. Quiero que el usuario final me visualice un resumen de unas ventas, de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es en un GridView
Uso un SELECT para mostrar los datos de Código 1 y OTRO Select para los de Código 2. Mi pregunta es si puedo agregar solamente un SELECT para las filas Alternas, y otras para las demás.
Este método me muestra Codigo1 pero necesito llamar a otro SELECT para ver Codigo2

```
  private void MostrarGird()
{
    DataTable dttr = new DataTable();
    OdbcCommand cmdd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT SlpCode FROM Vendedores WHERE SlpName = ?", cn);
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nombre", ListBox1.SelectedValue);
    OdbcDataAdapter dda = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmdd);
    dda.Fill(dttr);
    if (dttr.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        DataTable dta = new DataTable();
        DataRow fila = dttr.Rows[0];
        OdbcCommand cmda = new OdbcCommand("SELECT T0.ItemCode as Codigo, sum(Convert(int,A.VPiezas)) as Cantidad, sum(Convert(money, (A.VImporte)))/sum(Convert(money,(A.VPiezas))) as PrecioU FROM Articulos T0 INNER JOIN Codigos T1 ON T0.[ItemCode] = T1.[Code] INNER JOIN Code T2 ON T1.[Code] = T2.[Father] INNER JOIN Articulos T3 ON T2.[Code] = T3.[ItemCode] INNER JOIN SVenta A ON A.Codigo1 = T0.ItemCode WHERE T0.TreeType = 'T' and T3.ItmsGrpCod in (110, 119) and A.SlpCode = ? and A.Fecha = ? group by T0.ItemCode union SELECT T0.ItemCode as Codigo, sum(Convert(int,A.VKilos)) as Cantidad, sum(Convert(money, (A.VImporte)))/sum(Convert(money,(A.VKilos))) as PrecioU FROM Articulos T0 INNER JOIN Codigos T1 ON T0.[ItemCode] = T1.[Code] INNER JOIN Code T2 ON T1.[Code] = T2.[Father] INNER JOIN Articulos T3 ON T2.[Code] = T3.[ItemCode] INNER JOIN SVenta A ON A.Codigo2 = T0.ItemCode WHERE T0.TreeType = 'T' and T3.ItmsGrpCod in (111) and A.SlpCode = ? and A.Fecha = ? group by T0.ItemCode", cn);
        cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("codigo", Convert.ToString(fila["SlpCode"]));
        cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("fecha", DateTime.Parse(Fecha.Text));
        cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("codig", Convert.ToString(fila["SlpCode"]));
        cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("feca", DateTime.Parse(Fecha.Text));
        OdbcDataAdapter daa = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmda);
        daa.Fill(dta);
        GRILLA.DataSource = dta;
        GRILLA.DataBind();
    }
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Podrias mostrar un poco mejor que tenes y que tratas de agregar? y lo ideal, es que si esto es una vista, se agregue directamente en la vista.

Comment: Perdon pero no entiendo tu pregunta.  Ademas siempre es mejor que agregues tu codigo para que sea mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: Ya edite mi pregunta a ver si me doy a entender un poco mejor.